# Cannot use insert statement in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, insert

Please someone advise me. I am trying to make some error log in DB. I am writing the below query to insert data to table having 2 filednames only.
But I am getting error as:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -

```
INSERT INTO QISWEBLOG (DATETIME, MESSAGE) VALUES (
    '2017/12/24 01:01:48',
    Status ='0' INSPECTOPERATOR = '122018  ' INSPECTDATETIME = [20171201040930] MANAGEOPERATOR = [MIS] MANAGEDATETIME = [20171224130133] [StockGumUpdate Barcode] = [21T399--A02 BU60212CTBSID0]
)
```

> Error at Command Line : 4 Column : 8
>   Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
>   00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

My query is:

```
Dim text1 As String
text1 = "Status = '" & status & "' INSPECTOPERATOR = '" & inspectOperator & "' INSPECTDATETIME = '" & inspectDateTime & "' MANAGEOPERATOR = '" & manageOperator & "' MANAGEDATETIME = '" & manageDateTime & "' [StockGumUpdate Barcode] = '" & GridView1.Rows(index).Cells(1).Text & "'"
sqlStr = "INSERT INTO QISWEBLOG (DATETIME, MESSAGE)"
sqlStr = sqlStr & " VALUES ('" & Trim(CStr(Format(DateTime.Now, 
    "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"))) & "','" & text1 & "')"
```

Please help where I am wrong.

Comment: Add a breakpoint and see what command did you generate and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip (or escape) all the single quotes in your text1 variable. To escape a single quote, you need to type it twice.

Status =''0'' etc...

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve it after removing quotes.